# Publishing OSM data in GeoServer that has been imported into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to publish data on GeoServer.

I'm using Postgres/PostGIS and I've used osm2pgsql to load the data into the database.

I've configured a store correctly (I can see the tables from the database listed when I add a new layer and choose the store).

However when I go to add a new layer, what I see is different to the manual at geoserver (refer [Publishing a PostGIS Table](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/gettingstarted/postgis-quickstart/index.html)). The point that is different is the "Create a Layer" section, step 3 and 4. On step 3 it states the following:

> From the New Layer chooser drop-down menu, select `cite:nyc_buidings`.

I choose the data store and then get the list of layer names in the form:

[image]

The above screen shot is different to the doco for point 4. The doco for point 4 is as follows:

[image]

While I expect the names to be different, the problem is that none of the names are selectable. The only text that is selectable is `Publish`. It's slightly confusing, partly because I've not been able to find any example specific to what I'm trying to do, so I've had a lot of missteps along the way and have learnt the hard way not to make any presumptions.

My question is: is the `Publish` action against each table the same as the selectable text in the doco?

My concern is that I don't want to accidentally publish all the data in a table.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to my question, the answer is yes. The publish link is the same as what is currently shown in the documentation.

When I click publish I get similar options to what is shown in the documentation, albeit with a lot more options. I was able to successfully publish the layer for the PostGIS by guessing on the field that I needed to populate from the existing doco.

Apparently the documentation at GeoServer hasn't been updated to reflect changes with screens.

I also had to add a style that supported the data from OSM. I found a reference to one that supports the roads at http://blog.geoserver.org/2009/01/30/geoserver-and-openstreetmap/, which was very useful (refer to the styling section in the blog post).